# Button click function not being called the second time of button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, onclick

I have an MVC application and one of the views contains a button with a condition.

```
<a href="#DidNotEatModal" role="button" class="btn btnDidNotEat" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o"></i>Did Not Eat</a>   

<button type="button" id="btnRemoveDidNotEat" class="btn btnRemoveDidNotEat">Remove Did Not Eat</button>
```

- On click of btnRemoveDidNotEat,btnRemoveDidNotEat is hidden.
- If btnDidNotEat is clicked,btnRemoveDidNotEat  is shown.

Here is my JS code.

```
    $('.btnDidNotEat').on('click', function () {   
        $.ajax({

        }).done(function (partialViewResult) {        
            $('#btnRemoveDidNotEat').show();
        });
    });


    $('#btnRemoveDidNotEat').on('click', function () {   
        $.ajax({     

        }).done(function (partialViewResult) {                       
            $('#btnRemoveDidNotEat').hide();
        });
    });
```

The functionality works for the first time. On click of ".btnDidNotEat", the other button '#btnRemoveDidNotEat' is shown. On click of '#btnRemoveDidNotEat', it is hidden as required.

However the second time,On click of ".btnDidNotEat", the other button '#btnRemoveDidNotEat' is shown. But the button click function for '#btnRemoveDidNotEat' is not called.

I have tried doing the same with style="display:none;", but that gives me the same issue. I have also tried using toggle.

Am I missing something?

EDIT : Simplified the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You need to show the code in your ajax call - best guess is that your updating the DOM and replacing some of those elements, in which case you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes I think that is the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question right, but it looks like your AJAX response seems to have a partial view result. If you are trying to access the button click event of that partial view of AJAX, it will not hit the click event because it will not be attached to the DOM. So instead of your code, you should use something like this.

```
$("body").on("click", ".btnRemoveDidNotEat", function() {
    $.ajax({     

    }).done(function (partialViewResult) {                       
        $('#btnRemoveDidNotEat').hide();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but here is what I got [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ehzm31ua/)

Here is some improvements of your script:

```
$('.btnDidNotEat').click(function () {   
    $.ajax({

    }).done(function (partialViewResult) {        
        $('#btnRemoveDidNotEat').toggle();
    });
});


$('#btnRemoveDidNotEat').click(function () {   
    $.ajax({     

    }).done(function (partialViewResult) {                       
        $('#btnRemoveDidNotEat').toggle();
    });
});
```

You can use `toggle()` function instead of adding and deleting class.

Comment: Used the same fiddle code you used in my code,and the #btnRemoveDidNotEat is hidden the first time I click .btnDidNotEat and is never shown again irrespective of the number of times .btnDidNotEat is clicked.
I also don't see any console error.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I used 2.2.4 in my example, may be this is the problem